# Glade GTK entry get text

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, glade

Sorry for a newbie question but I could not figure out how to print a text which a user enter in a GTKEntry field after he press a button.

I design my app with glade, a simple TextEntry Field and a button. After I change the code of myappWindow.py:

```
  def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    print 'pressed'

  def entry1_changed_cb(self, widget, data=None):
    return widget.get_text ()
```

But now I couldn't find out how to print the text of the entry field after the user pressed the button.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `get_object` function of your builder to get the entry widget, for example

```
entry = self.builder.get_object('entry1')
print entry.get_text()
```

This assumes that `self.builder` is a Gtk.Builder instance that you assigned for example in your `__init__` method using the `get_builder` function of the `helpers` module in `yourproject_lib`

Comment: Danke, sehr hilfreich!

Comment: If you are using Quickly and you've added your widget through Glade, you can also use `self.ui.entry1.get_text()`. Note that this is not standard GTK, simply a nice shortcut Quickly offers.